# How do I get the number of running instances per docker swarm service as a prometheus metric?

Tags: docker, service, docker-swarm, prometheus, metric

For me it seems impossible to get a reliable metric containing all services and their container states (and count).

Using the "last seen" from cadvisor does not work - it is unreliable; there are some open bugs... Using the docker metric I only get the number of total instances running, stopped,...

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be below query can help ..

```
count(count(container_tasks_state{container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name=~".+", container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id=~"$node_id"}) by (container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name))
```

Use above query in Grafana, prometheus being datasource.

Comment: This looks good. Now I have to find a way to resolve the node_id to hostname :-) (BTW: I have to leave out the outer count and add the `state="running"` to get what I want)